# Convert number to HEX in perl

Tags: perl

I need to convert a number to hex in perl. I'm using the following simple code:

```
my $n = 10;
print sprintf("%X", $n);
```

That will output:   **A**
That's correct, but I need always 2 bytes like:   0A

So for example:
90 will show 5A - 6 will show 06 - 10 will show 0A

How can I do that?

Comment: `%0X` for leading zero-padding

Comment: Nope! This: print sprintf("%0X", $n);  will print only 'A'  :(

Comment: ah, right. @ikegami's got it below. I forgot the length specifier, to say how many padding spaces there should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sprintf("%02X", $n)
```

Comment: @LucasRey You can click the checkbox to the left to accept it as the answer.